# ModSecurity: Disruptive actions can only be specified by chain starter rules

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

I want to modify the response content using ModSecurity only if the file resides on a particular directory. I implemented the rules like this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains /admin/" "phase:2,chain,t:none,t:urlDecode,t:lowercase,t:normalizePath,deny,log"

SecRule STREAM_OUTPUT_BODY "@rsub s/test/replaced_string/" "phase:4,t:none,log,pass,msg:'String replaced'"
```

But after writing this rule, when I restart apache2, modsecurity gives me an error: `ModSecurity: Disruptive actions can only be specified by chain starter rules`. I tried writing the rules other way round too but it didn't help.

Any idea why it happens ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rule makes no sense.

If its in the admin area deny it and look at next rule (chain), where you allow it to pass! Which is it? Block or pass?

Also you can't chain rules from two different phases (phase 2 in first rule in chain and phase 4 in second rule).

I'd suggest you probably want something like this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains /admin/" "phase:4,chain,t:none,t:urlDecode,t:lowercase,t:normalizePath,pass,log"
    SecRule STREAM_OUTPUT_BODY "@rsub s/test/replaced_string/" "t:none,log,msg:'String replaced'"
```

Comment: I tried using the way you said above but this time I am getting the following error:

`ModSecurity: Execution phases can only be specified by chain starter rules.`

Comment: Corrected to remove redundant phase:4 from second rule. Also not sure you can specifics log or not and message in second rule so you might have to remove those too.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your request is that you used `pass` in the second rule.

`Disruptive actions can only be specified by chain starter rules` means that disruptive actions (such as `pass`) can only be specified by chain starter rules (the first rule that starts the chain).

so you cannot use pass in the next rules that are part of a chain.